# Не подключается модуль Jupyter Notebook: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

При импорте модуля cv2 в Jupyter Notebook ругается что такого модуля нету. Пробовал устанавливать его через:

```sh
pip install opencv-python
conda install opencv-python
conda install opencv
```

Ничего из этого не решило проблему, даже саму анаконду уже переустановил. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт :)

Оказалось что я устанавливал без прав администратора и пакеты не могли нормально распаковаться в директорию анаконды